# Remove an item from a Collection (MembershipUserCollection) - Enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I use asp.net 4, ef 4 in c#.
I use `System.Web.Security` to manage users in my web application.

I have a collection of users in MembershipUserCollection and I need remove some users during a foreach on that collector.

I suppose it is impossible to remove an item from the collector when you are looping.
Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Please provide me a sample of code, thanks!

```
       MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        foreach (MembershipUser x in users)
        {
            if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(x.UserName, "CMS-AUTHOR"))
            {
                users.Remove(x.UserName);
            }
         }
```

---

Error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify an enumeration while traversing it - put the users to remove in a list then remove all of them once you are done enumerating:

```
   MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
   List<string> usersToRemove = new List<string>();
   foreach (MembershipUser x in users)
   {
        if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(x.UserName, "CMS-AUTHOR"))
            usersToRemove.Add(x.UserName);
   }
   foreach(string userName in usersToRemove)
         users.Remove(userName);
```

or shorter using LINQ:

```
var usersToRemove = Membership.GetAllUsers()
                              .Where( user => !Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "CMS-AUTHOR"))
                              .ToList();
usersToRemove.ForEach( user => users.Remove(user.UserName));
```

Comment: Hi I tried your first code and I have the same problem, the problem I suppose is in users.Remove(x.UserName)

Comment: @GlbboK: there was a line I forgot to take out - should work now

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a collection you are enumerating over (obviously). Try using LINQ.

users.ToList().RemoveAll(x => !Roles.InUserInRole(x.UserName, "CMS-AUTHOR"))

Comment: upvoted before I realized that there is a problem - this will only remove users from the temporary list, but not from the user's collection which is the intention of OP

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inherent in how you're going through the collection. Using foreach traverses the collection as an IEnumerable. When moving through the IEnumerable, all you have is a reference to the current element and a method to move you to the next one. When you change the contents of the enumerable, that process gets screwed up. Always consider the collection you are foreaching as immutable; you can change properties of elements, but you cannot change the structure of the collection by adding or removing elements.

Try something like this instead:

```
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
MembershipUserCollection deletedUsers = new MembershipUserCollection();
    foreach (MembershipUser x in users)
    {
        if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(x.UserName, "CMS-AUTHOR"))
        {
            deletedUsers.Add(x);
        }
     }

foreach(MembershipUser delete in deletedUsers)
{
    users.Remove(delete);
}
```

The difference is that you are not changing the collection you are enumerating. You can make this simpler with a little Linq:

```
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
//the difference is that the Select method creates a new enumerable that isolates changes to its source
foreach (MembershipUser x in users.Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(z=>!Roles.IsUserInRole(z.UserName, "CMS-AUTHOR")))
{
    users.Remove(z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, your first code help quite a lot. Unfotunatelly I can use Linq with System.Web.Security

Comment: If you can use foreach on a collection, you can use Linq. You just need to convert the collection from a non-generic to a generic, as the MembershipUserCollection type currently only implements the non-generic IEnumerable. You can do this by calling `OfType<MembershipUser>()` or `Cast<MembershipUser>()` on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about what the problem is: You can't modify a collection while you're enumerating it. That could cause all kinds of problems if it were allowed.

The collection should have a ToList(), ToArray(), or CopyTo() method, which will create a copy of the collection. Make a copy and loop over the copy. You can then modify the original collection in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like:

```
var usersToRemove = from user in users
                    where !Roles.IsUserInRole(x.UserName, "CMS-AUTHOR")
                    select user;

foreach(var u in usersToRemove)
{
   users.Remove(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
Tell me what do you think or if could be better implemented.
Thanks for your time.

```
        // Take all Users
        MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        // Create an empty collector for only User in Author
        MembershipUserCollection usersAuthors = new MembershipUserCollection();
        foreach (MembershipUser x in users)
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(x.UserName, "CMS-AUTHOR"))
            {
                usersAuthors.Add(x);
            }
        }
```